# How to build a product configurator à 'Tesla Design Studio' for a own product?

Tags: three.js, frontend

A friend of mine has a small business which sells individualized styluses and pens and I do the tech related stuff (eCommerce, Social Media) for him.

In our new webshop, we want to include a product configurator in the style of the [Tesla Design Studio](https://www.tesla.com/modelx/design). So that a user could choose the material/extras and it would render in a preview. What's a good way to do this? I was taking a look at three.js, but didn't really get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be really hard to render really convincing (as in realistic looking) 3D-Graphics, especially in the browser. This is probably why the tesla-site you mentioned doesn't even try to to this. It is simply overlaying and replacing images over each other.

For instance, this is the image it is loading if you select the black paintjob:
[image: tesla black paintjob]

This image is then simply laid over the other parts of the car.

If you just have configurable products (so you know in advance all possible options for all parameters) it will probably be a better solution (in terms of visual quality) to go that route and simply use pre-rendered images.

But if you really need to use 3D (maybe because user-uploaded images need to be rendered on the product), this would be roughly how you'd do it. Be aware that this won't be easy (but a lot of fun), especially if you don't have experience with 3D programming.

- get your hands on good 3D-models of the products
- export that model in a format understood by three.js and test how it will look
- tweak around the model, it's materials and settings until you have that single model in a good shape (attention: massive rabbit-hole here)

now that you have a single static model looking good, let's get to personalization:

- define the parts and properties that will be dynamic
- split up the 3D-model into these parts
- changing colors or materials is relatively simple, something like custom images a bit more complicated
- test a lot of different settings and make sure it still looks good enough

At this point you will have a properly configurable model, left to do is building a user-interface to control all these settings.

Depending on your experience, willingness to learn new stuff and most of all the level of quality you want this can take anything from a few days to several weeks to build, but I would like to encourage you to at least try the first few steps and see if you like that. Writing 3D programs is pretty awesome.

Comment: Hey Martin. Thanks for that comment! I posted this in several forums (e.g. Reddit) and this is the only answer I've got! And it was a really helpful as well. Thanks for that. I will try to experiment in the coming days/weeks.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice to hear you will give it a shot. And if questions come up along the way, stackoverflow is your friend :)